# Delphi - Save DateTime Null to DB (ADO / MySQL)

Tags: mysql, delphi, date, odbc, ado

I have a Delphi form with some DB controls on it.

To represent a date I use the `TJvDBDatePickerEdit` (from JCL), which has a nice property

```
ShowCheckBox := True;
```

to allow the user to enter that no date is known (DBNull).

I verify, that nulling the DatePicker works as expected by:

```
procedure Tframe.adoQueryBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if (qryAuftraege.FieldByName('MyDateField').IsNull) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('IsNull!');
  end;
end;
```

The message box shows. So the field that the ADO Component should write is of type varNull.

Now there is this pipeline:

```
TADOQuery -> TADOConnection -> MS OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers -> MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver
```

And the MySQL ODBC driver now shows in it's log:

```
UPDATE `db`.`table` SET `MyDateField`=_latin1'0004-00-00' WHERE `ID`=5 AND `MyDateField`=_latin1'2009-06-17';
```

Well, the date is stored as `'0004-00-00'` (which MySQL seems to save like that).
Now when querying the entry, it is recognized as Null by Delphi, but when it shall be updated the next time, calling:

```
UPDATE `bvl`.`auftraege` SET `MyDateField`=_latin1'2009-06-17' WHERE `ID`=5 AND `MyDateField` IS NULL;
```

of course fails, because MyDateField is NOT NULL (at least in the MySQL DB).

Where does this string `'0004-00-00'` come from? If it is a bug somewhere, where could I possibly intercept it?

I already know that there are components to buy that provide direct MySQL connections which (I assume) don't show this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to check your MySQL options as discussed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-date.html)...

Then, I would try with a different set of connection components as the stack (ADO + ODBC 5.1 driver) might the problem here.
Have you tried with another ODBC driver? 
Or with DBX...

Comment: although I didn't try it, I guess you're right about the problem being in the stack. I will now switch to Postgres (which has a better fitting licensing model) because I am not bound to MySQL. Probably I will also try Zeoslib then. Thanks.

Comment: Since this questions seems to get attention: Switching to Postgres with Zeoslib solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

To save a null date/time to the database record, just call

```
qryAuftraege.FieldByName('MyDateField').clear;
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated the MyDateField value of the ADOQuery is already Null, the clear() method doesn't change this nor the wrong behaviour of the driver afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the implications of doing this, but I've always used

```
qryAuftraege.FieldByName('MyDateField').AsString:='';
```

Comment: Totally wrong. Most RDBMSs differentiate between NULL (no value assigned) and '' (empty string assigned). Oracle is the only mainstream RDBMS that doesn't consider the NULL and '' as different.

Comment: And Firebird too, I've used it for about 5 years and never have a problem doing this

Comment: thanks for the hint, as the other two comments said this is not exactly what I wanted, though surprisingly it seems to have the same effect (it is actually NULL then).
But the error is still AFTER that, when the driver assigns '0004-00-00' in the actual database field